# Return how many objects in an arraylist whose model year is between these two ints (parameters)...? java

Tags: java, arraylist

My programming prof is obsessed with Lamborghini's so we always do assignments related to them in some way...

Instance variables from LamborghiniCarLot class...

```
getModelYear() //returns the year

private ArrayList <Lamborghini> inventory; //an arraylist made up of Lamborghini(another class) objects
```

Method coding:

```
public int howManyBetweenTheseYears(int startYear, int endYear)
{
    //returns the number of lamborghinis in the inventory whose model year is between these numbers,     inclusive
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else..

EDIT1: I've tried this:

```
public int howManyBetweenTheseYears(int startYear, int endYear)
{
    Iterator<Lamborghini> i = inventory.iterator();
    int n = 0;
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Lamborghini lambo = i.next();

        if((lambo.getModelYear() >= startYear) && (lambo.getModelYear() <= endYear)){
            n++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(n);
    return n;


}
```

It compiles with the rest of my assignment but it doesn't work with the testing class, which was expected. In the testing class, I get the NullPointerException error.

EDIT2: I've gotten rid of the NPE error and my testing class compiles, but I don't get the correct return value with this coding:

```
public int howManyBetweenTheseYears(int startYear, int endYear)
{
    int n = 0;
    for(Lamborghini l : inventory){
        while((l.getModelYear()>=startYear) && (l.getModelYear()<= endYear)){
            n++;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

When startYear is 2010 and endYear is 2012, the int returned should be 3 buts its 0. Tested with other years and the result is always 0.

Comment: Which line throws the NPE?

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
private ArrayList<Lamborghini> inventory;
```

it defaults to `null`. So it's the same as,

```
private ArrayList<Lamborghini> inventory = null;
```

and so you get a NPE when you try iterate it. Also, you should use the interface type. So, change it to something like

```
private List<Lamborghini> inventory = new ArrayList<>();
```

But, you'll still need to add `Lamborghini`(s) to your `inventory`.